# Backup /var/lib/docker without images?

Tags: docker

I want to make a backup of all my containers and volumes, so the easiest way would be to copy `/var/lib/docker` to another location.

However this directory also includes all the images, and I don't want to include them since they all can easily be re-downloaded from public sources.

So how can I copy this directory while excluding the images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to differentiate between container backup and vol backup:

### Backing up a container, that is, its configurations like labels, envs, etc.

You do that by committing the container as an image:

```
$ docker container commit <container-name/id> <name-of-new-image>
```

Better give it also some metainfo:

```
$ docker container ...  -m "very important container config state" -a "John Doe"
```

### Backing up a volume

Let's say the volume of interest `<my-vol>` is bound to a container `<other-container>` - which may have been created like: `docker container run -v /my-vol other-container ...`

So first you have to bind the volume also to a newly created temporary container with the `--volumes-from` flag. With the `-v` option you mount a local path (of the host) into the container:

```
$ docker container run -rm --volumes-from <other-container> \
-v <dir/on/host>:<mountpath/in/container> \
<ubuntu/centos/whatever-base-image> tar cvf <mountpath/in/container>/backup.tar /<my-vol>
```

After completing the command the container stops and with that it will also be deleted because of the -rm option.

Whith all that the steps are:

- bind the volume to a temp container
- mount a hostpath into the container
- make a tarbal (or whatever kind of backup)
  of the volume in the container
- container stops and is deleted after the backup command has finished
- the backup tarbal is left on the mounted dir of the container host.

see also: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

---

### Shell Command

.. the other - not recommended - way would be to do it just with os level commands:

```
shopt -s extglob
cp -r var/lib/docker/!(image) your/path/backup
```

For that you have to stop all involved containers to prevent read/write issues.